# Conditionally assign Laravel's controller values on Construct method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller

I work with a Laravel porject that uses an array of Model attributes to show it on the view. Unlike most Laravel prokects where do you send a set of data to the view and you choose how to show it on our project that's defined on a Controller's variable.

This variable ($showFields) expects an array of Model's atributes and the values are shown on the view.

The thing is that I need to adapt the shown atributes based on one atrubute's id (vendor_id). My idea is, based on the vendor_id assign one array of attributes or another.

I've been trying with the Controller's constructor method but it's not working as when it's called seems like it does not have the values yet. Is this even possible?

This is the controller's code:

```
protected $showFields = []; // This is the variable that tells the view what attributes to show

protected $vendorInformation =  [...];

protected $noVendorInformation = [...];

public function __construct(QuoteService $quoteService)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->quoteService = $quoteService;

    if($this->vendor_id === xx){
        array_push($this->showFields, $this->noVendorInformation);
    } else {
        array_push($this->showFields, $this->vendorInformation);
    }

}
```

I'm working with Laravel 5.7

Comment: try to use the repository design pattern with having different interfaces use dependency injection using containers to pass classes with different interfaces, why use the constructor in controller?

Comment: I though on using the Constructor method because I need to populate the $showFields as soon the constructor is initialized to be available to pass the values to the view.

Comment: but I guess it is a antipattern use repository as call 2 different classes with same interface as per your condition. (also in above comment it is different classes not interfaces)

Comment: finally what I did is to retrieve the model by id on the constructor and then check the vendor_id. It's true that it's sloppy but I do not know where to place it then.